# Merging groupby objects?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, left-join

What's the way to do a left join on grouped pandas dataframes (I think these become groupby objects)?

I have a df that looks like this:

[image]

This one is `df_output_pacer`. I have another df called `df_archives_gb` with the exact same structure, but with some extra months added. I'd like to left join them like

```
df_comparer = pd.merge(df_output_pacer, df_archives_gb, how='left', on=['Month', 'Bucket'])
```

However, it doesn't work:

> KeyError: 'Month'

Even though there is a `Month` field in both df's. What am I missing? Is there a special way you have to merge groupby objects? How?

Comment: Also, add a [mcve] please.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `join`

```
df_output_pacer.join(df_archives_gb.rename(columns={'sum':'sum1'}),how='left')
```

Update :

```
pd.concat([df_output_pacer,df_archives_gb.reindex(df_archives_gb.index)],1)
```

Comment: @lte__ maybe try pd.concat ?

Comment: that's not what I want to do... Concat will put the two DFs "after" each other with the same number of columns. I want to add a new column (~join)

Comment: Oh ok I figured out why, not sure how to fix. So the year has changed: `Month` is (18-01) in the first df and (17-01) on the second. So question: Can I just join on the `Bucket`?

Comment: @lte__ without the data that is all I can do

Comment: @lte__ and I think there is a better way , maybe unstack  your mutiple index ?